# C#: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 127.0.0.1:1026

Tags: python, c#, tcp

back again with more TCP questions :(

Ive coded the server side listener, and client side sender, but I'm getting the error:

> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException:
> 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. 127.0.0.1:1026'

The code for the server is in python, and is:

```
def StartServer(Host, Port, Log):
    ServerSocket = sockets.socket(sockets.AF_INET, sockets.SOCK_STREAM)
    SererSocket.bind((Host, Port))
    ServerSocket.listen(1)

    Log.log(f"Listening on {Host}:{Port}")
    
    while True:
        ClientSocket, Addr = ServerSocket.accept()
        Data = ClientSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        response = "data recieved"
        ClientSocket.send(response.encode("utf-8"))
        ClientSocket.close()
```

And the code for the server is in C# (.net6.0), and is:

```
public static void SendData(string serverAddress, int port)
{
    TcpClient client = new(serverAddress, port);

    Console.WriteLine("1");

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    Console.WriteLine("2");

    // Send data to server
    string message = "Hello from C# client";
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("3");

    // Receive response from server
    data = new byte[256];
    int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received from server: {responseData}");

    Console.WriteLine("4");

    // Close the connection
    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
}
```

I am binding the python server to 127.0.01:1026 (the port is available as far as I'm aware), and I receive the error when creating a TCP Client, using "127.0.0.1", 1026. I have tried disabling the firewall on both ends to no luck. Does anyone know what my issue is?

EDIT: I am running the server and client on different machines on the same internet connection, but intend to switch the client to different connections at a later stage.

Comment: I am not sure that connecting to 127.0.0.1 from a different computer will work. Since the firewall is configured to allow the two connect, run `hostname` in the command of your server computer, and try using that instead of 127.0.0.1 on your client computer.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is "this machine".  You cannot use it to talk between machines.

Comment: @jaabh this worked perfectly !!! thanks so much for your help - Ive been forced by my professor to learn TCP despite never using it which is an absolute pain, but i finally got a response from the server !!!! Thanks so much :)))

Answer (score 0):

It was just me being inexperienced using TCP/IP. I changed the binding from 127.0.0.1:1026 to (My IP):1026 on both the client and the server, which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is trying to connect from two different computers using 127.0.0.1.

Run `hostname` in the command on the server computer and use that to connect from the client instead of 127.0.0.1.